# Git untracked files preventing checkout

Tags: git

I'm on the branch `stage` and i have capitalized all filenames, i want to checkout to branch `develop` but this error appears.

The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:

```
application/controllers/cast_roles.php
        application/controllers/home_page_sliders.php
        application/controllers/invite_friend.php
        application/controllers/signup_page_movies.php
        application/controllers/special_users.php
        application/controllers/upload_media.php
```

These files are there but they've been capitalized.

e.g.

```
application/controllers/Cast_roles.php
application/controllers/Home_page_sliders.php
```

How do i solve?  Is there a way to remove file case sensitive?

Comment: Do you want to discard changes or do you want to keep them? Was capitaizing the only change since the last commit?

Comment: What operating system are you on?  Have you changed your `core.ignorecase` setting?  Can you paste the output of `git config --list --show-origin`?

Answer (score 1):

Remove untracked file and Do again:

```
git clean -f -d
```

Comment: Careful with `git clean`, be sure to understand what is going to be cleaned. A `--dry-run` is good practice before the real thing.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck at the same problem. For some files the capitalization was changed. These changes are commited, but git/IntelliJ are not able to switch between with and without the change.

At the end, I have always to do a `git checkout theOtherBranch --force`.